# Dead pixel band on ST7735 TFT display with Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, numpy, raspberry-pi2, display

I'm working on a project which involves driving a 1.44" TFT display using a Raspberry Pi.  The display is: https://www.adafruit.com/product/2088

The RPi is a RPi2 Mobel B V1.1

The Library I'm using to drive the Display is here:
https://github.com/cskau/Python_ST7735

My pins are wired as follows:

```
===== DISPLAY =====        == GPIO ==
LITE    (BACKLIGHT)        not used
CCS     (SD chip select)   not used
SCK     (SCLK)             pin 23 (GPIO 11)
SI      (MOSI)             pin 19 (GPIO 10)
SO      (MISO)             pin 21 (GPIO 9)
TCS     (TFT chipselect)   pin 24 (GPIO 8)
RST     (RESET)            pin 22 (GPIO 25)
D/C     (data/command)     pin 18 (GPIO 24)
GND     (GND)              GND (pin 6)
3v3     (3.3v in)          not used
VCC     (VCC)              5v
```

As of right now, my code is very simple, just a modification of the examples that came with the library:

```
from PIL import Image
import ST7735 as TFT
import Adafruit_GPIO as GPIO
import Adafruit_GPIO.SPI as SPI
import time
import os

WIDTH = 128
HEIGHT = 128
SPEED_HZ = 32000000

# Raspberry Pi configuration.
DC = 24
RST = 25
SPI_PORT = 0
SPI_DEVICE = 0

# Create TFT LCD display class.
disp = TFT.ST7735(
    DC,
    rst=RST,
    spi=SPI.SpiDev(
        SPI_PORT,
        SPI_DEVICE,
        max_speed_hz=SPEED_HZ))

# Initialize display.
disp.begin()

image =Image.open('image1.GIF')
try:
    while 1:
        image.seek(image.tell()+1)
        disp.display(image)
        if(image.tell()==242):
            image.seek(0)
            time.sleep(2)
except EOFError:
    pass
```

Here is the library code:

```
import numbers
import time
import numpy as np

from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageDraw

import Adafruit_GPIO as GPIO
import Adafruit_GPIO.SPI as SPI


# SPI_CLOCK_HZ = 64000000 # 64 MHz
SPI_CLOCK_HZ = 32000000 # 32 MHz


# Constants for interacting with display registers.
ST7735_TFTWIDTH    = 128
ST7735_TFTHEIGHT   = 160

ST7735_NOP         = 0x00
ST7735_SWRESET     = 0x01
ST7735_RDDID       = 0x04
ST7735_RDDST       = 0x09

ST7735_SLPIN       = 0x10
ST7735_SLPOUT      = 0x11
ST7735_PTLON       = 0x12
ST7735_NORON       = 0x13

# ILI9341_RDMODE      = 0x0A
# ILI9341_RDMADCTL    = 0x0B
# ILI9341_RDPIXFMT    = 0x0C
# ILI9341_RDIMGFMT    = 0x0A
# ILI9341_RDSELFDIAG  = 0x0F

ST7735_INVOFF      = 0x20
ST7735_INVON       = 0x21
# ILI9341_GAMMASET    = 0x26
ST7735_DISPOFF     = 0x28
ST7735_DISPON      = 0x29

ST7735_CASET       = 0x2A
ST7735_RASET       = 0x2B
ST7735_RAMWR       = 0x2C
ST7735_RAMRD       = 0x2E

ST7735_PTLAR       = 0x30
ST7735_MADCTL      = 0x36
# ST7735_PIXFMT      = 0x3A
ST7735_COLMOD       = 0x3A

ST7735_FRMCTR1     = 0xB1
ST7735_FRMCTR2     = 0xB2
ST7735_FRMCTR3     = 0xB3
ST7735_INVCTR      = 0xB4
# ILI9341_DFUNCTR     = 0xB6
ST7735_DISSET5      = 0xB6


ST7735_PWCTR1      = 0xC0
ST7735_PWCTR2      = 0xC1
ST7735_PWCTR3      = 0xC2
ST7735_PWCTR4      = 0xC3
ST7735_PWCTR5      = 0xC4
ST7735_VMCTR1      = 0xC5
# ILI9341_VMCTR2      = 0xC7

ST7735_RDID1       = 0xDA
ST7735_RDID2       = 0xDB
ST7735_RDID3       = 0xDC
ST7735_RDID4       = 0xDD

ST7735_GMCTRP1     = 0xE0
ST7735_GMCTRN1     = 0xE1

ST7735_PWCTR6      = 0xFC

# Colours for convenience
ST7735_BLACK       = 0x0000 # 0b 00000 000000 00000
ST7735_BLUE        = 0x001F # 0b 00000 000000 11111
ST7735_GREEN       = 0x07E0 # 0b 00000 111111 00000
ST7735_RED         = 0xF800 # 0b 11111 000000 00000
ST7735_CYAN        = 0x07FF # 0b 00000 111111 11111
ST7735_MAGENTA     = 0xF81F # 0b 11111 000000 11111
ST7735_YELLOW      = 0xFFE0 # 0b 11111 111111 00000
ST7735_WHITE       = 0xFFFF # 0b 11111 111111 11111


def color565(r, g, b):
    """Convert red, green, blue components to a 16-bit 565 RGB value. Components
    should be values 0 to 255.
    """
    return ((r & 0xF8) << 8) | ((g & 0xFC) << 3) | (b >> 3)

def image_to_data(image):
    """Generator function to convert a PIL image to 16-bit 565 RGB bytes."""
    # NumPy is much faster at doing this. NumPy code provided by:
    # Keith (https://www.blogger.com/profile/02555547344016007163)
    pb = np.array(image.convert('RGB')).astype('uint16')
    color = ((pb[:,:,0] & 0xF8) << 8) | ((pb[:,:,1] & 0xFC) << 3) | (pb[:,:,2] >> 3)
    return np.dstack(((color >> 8) & 0xFF, color & 0xFF)).flatten().tolist()

class ST7735(object):
    """Representation of an ST7735 TFT LCD."""

    def __init__(self, dc, spi, rst=None, gpio=None, width=ST7735_TFTWIDTH,
        height=ST7735_TFTHEIGHT):
        """Create an instance of the display using SPI communication.  Must
        provide the GPIO pin number for the D/C pin and the SPI driver.  Can
        optionally provide the GPIO pin number for the reset pin as the rst
        parameter.
        """
        self._dc = dc
        self._rst = rst
        self._spi = spi
        self._gpio = gpio
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        if self._gpio is None:
            self._gpio = GPIO.get_platform_gpio()
        # Set DC as output.
        self._gpio.setup(dc, GPIO.OUT)
        # Setup reset as output (if provided).
        if rst is not None:
            self._gpio.setup(rst, GPIO.OUT)
        # Set SPI to mode 0, MSB first.
        spi.set_mode(0)
        spi.set_bit_order(SPI.MSBFIRST)
        spi.set_clock_hz(SPI_CLOCK_HZ)
        # Create an image buffer.
        self.buffer = Image.new('RGB', (width, height))

    def send(self, data, is_data=True, chunk_size=4096):
        """Write a byte or array of bytes to the display. Is_data parameter
        controls if byte should be interpreted as display data (True) or command
        data (False).  Chunk_size is an optional size of bytes to write in a
        single SPI transaction, with a default of 4096.
        """
        # Set DC low for command, high for data.
        self._gpio.output(self._dc, is_data)
        # Convert scalar argument to list so either can be passed as parameter.
        if isinstance(data, numbers.Number):
            data = [data & 0xFF]
        # Write data a chunk at a time.
        for start in range(0, len(data), chunk_size):
            end = min(start+chunk_size, len(data))
            self._spi.write(data[start:end])

    def command(self, data):
        """Write a byte or array of bytes to the display as command data."""
        self.send(data, False)

    def data(self, data):
        """Write a byte or array of bytes to the display as display data."""
        self.send(data, True)

    def reset(self):
        """Reset the display, if reset pin is connected."""
        if self._rst is not None:
            self._gpio.set_high(self._rst)
            time.sleep(0.500)
            self._gpio.set_low(self._rst)
            time.sleep(0.500)
            self._gpio.set_high(self._rst)
            time.sleep(0.500)

    def _init(self):
        # Initialize the display.  Broken out as a separate function so it can
        # be overridden by other displays in the future.

        self.command(ST7735_SWRESET) # Software reset
        time.sleep(0.150) # delay 150 ms

        self.command(ST7735_SLPOUT) # Out of sleep mode
        time.sleep(0.500) # delay 500 ms

        self.command(ST7735_FRMCTR1) # Frame rate ctrl - normal mode
        self.data(0x01) # Rate = fosc/(1x2+40) * (LINE+2C+2D)
        self.data(0x2C)
        self.data(0x2D)

        self.command(ST7735_FRMCTR2) # Frame rate ctrl - idle mode
        self.data(0x01) # Rate = fosc/(1x2+40) * (LINE+2C+2D)
        self.data(0x2C)
        self.data(0x2D)

        self.command(ST7735_FRMCTR3) # Frame rate ctrl - partial mode
        self.data(0x01) # Dot inversion mode
        self.data(0x2C)
        self.data(0x2D)
        self.data(0x01) # Line inversion mode
        self.data(0x2C)
        self.data(0x2D)

        self.command(ST7735_INVCTR) # Display inversion ctrl
        self.data(0x07) # No inversion

        self.command(ST7735_PWCTR1) # Power control
        self.data(0xA2)
        self.data(0x02) # -4.6V
        self.data(0x84) # auto mode

        self.command(ST7735_PWCTR2) # Power control
        self.data(0x0A) # Opamp current small
        self.data(0x00) # Boost frequency

        self.command(ST7735_PWCTR4) # Power control
        self.data(0x8A) # BCLK/2, Opamp current small & Medium low
        self.data(0x2A)

        self.command(ST7735_PWCTR5) # Power control
        self.data(0x8A)
        self.data(0xEE)

        self.command(ST7735_VMCTR1) # Power control
        self.data(0x0E)

        self.command(ST7735_INVOFF) # Don't invert display

        self.command(ST7735_MADCTL) # Memory access control (directions)
        self.data(0xC8) # row addr/col addr, bottom to top refresh

        self.command(ST7735_COLMOD) # set color mode
        self.data(0x05) # 16-bit color

        #

        self.command(ST7735_CASET) # Column addr set
        self.data(0x00) # XSTART = 0
        self.data(0x00)
        self.data(0x00) # XEND = 127
        self.data(0x7F)

        self.command(ST7735_RASET) # Row addr set
        self.data(0x00) # XSTART = 0
        self.data(0x00)
        self.data(0x00) # XEND = 159
        self.data(0x9F)

        #

        self.command(ST7735_GMCTRP1) # Set Gamma
        self.data(0x02)
        self.data(0x1c)
        self.data(0x07)
        self.data(0x12)
        self.data(0x37)
        self.data(0x32)
        self.data(0x29)
        self.data(0x2d)
        self.data(0x29)
        self.data(0x25)
        self.data(0x2B)
        self.data(0x39)
        self.data(0x00)
        self.data(0x01)
        self.data(0x03)
        self.data(0x10)

        self.command(ST7735_GMCTRN1) # Set Gamma
        self.data(0x03)
        self.data(0x1d)
        self.data(0x07)
        self.data(0x06)
        self.data(0x2E)
        self.data(0x2C)
        self.data(0x29)
        self.data(0x2D)
        self.data(0x2E)
        self.data(0x2E)
        self.data(0x37)
        self.data(0x3F)
        self.data(0x00)
        self.data(0x00)
        self.data(0x02)
        self.data(0x10)

        self.command(ST7735_NORON) # Normal display on
        time.sleep(0.10) # 10 ms

        self.command(ST7735_DISPON) # Display on
        time.sleep(0.100) # 100 ms

    def begin(self):
        """Initialize the display.  Should be called once before other calls that
        interact with the display are called.
        """
        self.reset()
        self._init()

    def set_window(self, x0=0, y0=0, x1=None, y1=None):
        """Set the pixel address window for proceeding drawing commands. x0 and
        x1 should define the minimum and maximum x pixel bounds.  y0 and y1
        should define the minimum and maximum y pixel bound.  If no parameters
        are specified the default will be to update the entire display from 0,0
        to width-1,height-1.
        """
        if x1 is None:
            x1 = self.width-1
        if y1 is None:
            y1 = self.height-1
        self.command(ST7735_CASET)        # Column addr set
        self.data(x0 >> 8)
        self.data(x0)                    # XSTART
        self.data(x1 >> 8)
        self.data(x1)                    # XEND
        self.command(ST7735_RASET)        # Row addr set
        self.data(y0 >> 8)
        self.data(y0)                    # YSTART
        self.data(y1 >> 8)
        self.data(y1)                    # YEND
        self.command(ST7735_RAMWR)        # write to RAM

    def display(self, image=None):
        """Write the display buffer or provided image to the hardware.  If no
        image parameter is provided the display buffer will be written to the
        hardware.  If an image is provided, it should be RGB format and the
        same dimensions as the display hardware.
        """
        # By default write the internal buffer to the display.
        if image is None:
            image = self.buffer
        # Set address bounds to entire display.
        self.set_window()
        # Convert image to array of 16bit 565 RGB data bytes.
        # Unfortunate that this copy has to occur, but the SPI byte writing
        # function needs to take an array of bytes and PIL doesn't natively
        # store images in 16-bit 565 RGB format.
        pixelbytes = list(image_to_data(image))
        # Write data to hardware.
        self.data(pixelbytes)

    def clear(self, color=(0,0,0)):
        """Clear the image buffer to the specified RGB color (default black)."""
        width, height = self.buffer.size
        self.buffer.putdata([color]*(width*height))

    def draw(self):
        """Return a PIL ImageDraw instance for 2D drawing on the image buffer."""
        return ImageDraw.Draw(self.buffer)
```

Here's my issue: There is a dead pixel band around the edge of the display, 2 pixels wide on the right, 3 pixels wide on the bottom.  I have tried tinkering with the library (I had to, as it was written for a 128 X 160 display) and the code, but any time the height and width values are changed from 128 to another value the image gets horribly skewed.  How can I modify the library so that there isn't a band of dead pixels on my display?  I can provide images of the display in action if needed.

Comment: What's your question? What does it have to do with Python?

Comment: I added a question to the post.  Basically, what can I do to remove this band of dead pixels, because I believe the issue is with the code or library.  The code is easy enough to understand, but editing the library is a bit over my head.  Both the code and the library are in Python, but if adding a Python tag should be used for questions directly related to stuff like syntax, then I can remove the tag.

Comment: If the question is how to modify the Python code in the library, then you should include it in your question (or at least a link to it). However it sounds like it might actually be "How do I find and modify the library?"

Comment: I added in the library in its raw form.  the lines 
ST7735_TFTWIDTH    = 128
ST7735_TFTHEIGHT   = 160
have been edited to 
ST7735_TFTWIDTH    = 128
ST7735_TFTHEIGHT   = 128
because the display I'm working with is 128 by 128 pixels.  There's probably something I'm missing in the library besides these two lines that need to be edited.

Comment: That's much better—now someone may actually be able to help you.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the hardware it is yet another badly designed and manufactured cheap display. I bet you a penny that it has yellow header pins and not black header pins.

By experimentation you will find that you have a 128x128 pixel display mapped onto a 132x132 chunk of frame memory. In terms of exactly how it is positioned you will find the 128x128 display is 1 pixel down, 2 to the right, 2 to the left and 3 up from the borders of the frame memory.

This means that regardless of the screen rotation you use there will be a need to add offsets to your X and Y co-ordinates. This problem is also exhibited if you make use of scrolling.

A simple little data structure used to tell you X and Y offsets (all positive) in all four screen rotations is a convenient solution. Scrolling needs more space in your data structure but remember it can happen only along one axis.

The problem is surmountable. I just happened to be messing with this two weeks ago!

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  I just kept fiddling with all the variables one at a time and noted the differences.  Just like you said, weird mapping.  I was able to get it working, though.